# My computer often logs on at night (when I'm not using it)

Tags: windows, login, event-viewer

What does Windows Event Viewer mean by:

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       <<MYCOMPUTERNAME>>$
    Account Domain:     <<MYDOMAINNAME>>
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Logon Type:         5

Impersonation Level:        Impersonation

New Logon:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       SYSTEM
    Account Domain:     NT AUTHORITY
    Logon ID:       0x3E7
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x358
    Process Name:       C:\Windows\System32\services.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Advapi  
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

Who is this?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to worry about, most likely services performing automated tasks or scheduled tasks executing.

Comment: How to know which service does it?